# Automorphism of an integral domain extends to an automorphism of the quotient field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

> Every automorphism of an integral domain can be extended to an automorphism of its quotient field.

Please help to start with the proof!!

Comment: Maybe it's time for you to read this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4945#4945

Comment: How much context does this question need?  It seems to me it's pretty clear to anyone with a minimal education in abstract algebra; the context is general mathematical knowledge.  Probably everyone who voted to close it had enough education to provide the relevant context.  I'm not Ankit Ghosh's professor or TA; why should I care what he tried or didn't?  It's a good question as is:  clear, uncluttered and engaging.  Bluntly:  overcontextualization and turning this place into an extended TA session bugs me.  I say math for math's sake!  ***NB:*** I'm not a curmudgeon, but I play one on MSE.

Comment: ***Also***, allow me to say (by which I mean type) that it is not my intention to personally criticize those who voted to close.  But, being the man on the street, I want to know. Grump, grouse, gripe, bitch and moan.  I should get some sleep! Collegially Yours, R.L.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be an integral domain and let $k$ be it's field of fractions and let $i : A \to k$ be the canonical inclusion. Let $\phi : A \to A$ be an automorphism. Then $i\phi : A \to k$ is a homomorphism with the property that for every non-zero $a \in A, i\phi(a)$ is a unit in $k$ and every element of $k$ can be written as $(i\phi(a))(i\phi(b))^{-1}$ for some $a, b \in A, b \neq 0.$ Then by the *universal property of field of fractions*, there exists an isomorphism $\Phi : k \to k$ such that $i\phi = \Phi i.$